# SSH -D flag in config

Tags: ssh

I'm using SSH to direct my local internet traffic to a remote machine, using the following command:

```
ssh -D 4321 -N -v user@server
```

How do I add an entry to my `.ssh/config` file so that I can simple do `ssh user@server`?

*Specifically, how do I map the **-D** option to it's config-equivalent?*

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18704195/how-to-add-socks-proxy-to-ssh-config-file/19896699

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The equivalent `.ssh/config` entry for the `-D` option is `DynamicForward`.  It takes the same options as `-D`, and is applied on a per-host basis.

```
host server
    Username user
    DynamicForward localhost:4321
    RequestTTY no
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you have a reference that shows how `.ssh/config` entries map to the command line options?

Comment: This one I just knew, but my research strategy would be to look for keywords in the man page entry for ssh(1)'s `-D` option, then search for those keywords in the ssh_config(5) man page.  In this case, SOCKS.